# Firebase FCM Not Updating Invalid Token Swift After Closing App

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM to send push notifications to my app via Firebase Functions. I'm able to generate a token and send push notifications to the user, but as soon as they close out the app completely the token becomes invalid. I try to update the token with the method below, but it just returns the same token that's already in my database and that Firebase Functions says is invalid. That final method isn't called.

```
class PushNotificationManager: NSObject, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    let userID: String
    init(userID: String) {
        self.userID = userID
        super.init()
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded()
    }

    func updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded() {
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
            } else if let result = result {
                print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
                var ref: DatabaseReference!
                ref = Database.database().reference()
                ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).updateChildValues(["fcmToken" :  result.token])
            }
        }

    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).updateChildValues(["fcmToken" :  fcmToken])
    }
}
```